# Angular material not able to display data

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

Could someone tell me please what i'm doing wrong , i can't seem to get my data displayed on the tavle after being called from backend , though it is seen on the console

Ts

```
export class PatientsComponent implements OnInit  {
  patient: Patient [] = [];

  public displayedColumns = ['id', 'fullname', 'tribe', 'age' ];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Patient>();

  constructor(private userService:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.userService.getPatients().subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.dataSource.data = res;
    })
  }

}
```

Html

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>
   
        <ng-container matColumnDef="fullname">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fullname}} </td>
        </ng-container>
      
        <ng-container matColumnDef="tribe">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tribe </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tribe}} </td>
        </ng-container>
      
       
        <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Age</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
        </ng-container>
       
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
```

Interface

```
export interface Patient {
    id: String,
    fullname: String,
    tribe : String,
    age: String
}
```

AppMaterialModule

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';

@NgModule({
// since we're exporting these modules, add them to export
    exports: [
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
       
    ]
})
export class AppMaterialModule {}
```

app,module.ts

```
import { AppMaterialModule } from "./app.material-module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ....
  ],
  imports: [
    // .........
    AppMaterialModule,

  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

On page realoading i get an empty table that contains like hundred of empty rows andi can't just figure out why. Can somebody help me please

And on console there this [image]

Result
[image]

Comment: did you imported your modules?

Comment: yes i have , i've added them on the post could you please check

Comment: Use type `string` not the constructor `String`. Fix your console errors (load material icons in styles.css/style sheet in html) and In the http example they stick that data assignment to an ngAfterViewInit https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: Tried fixing all those but still i get nothing

Comment: Inside your subscribe function: `this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource<Patient>(res);`

Comment: Still not getting any data , on the console my data is seen

Comment: help please, still stuck

Comment: have you use "changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush" ?

Comment: Nope , i don't know what that does , is it in the documentation of material tables?

Comment: what do you mean by *tried fixing*? did you fix them? as posted, we don't have a minimal example to reproduce our issue in order to help.

Comment: I replaced the  `ngOnInIt`  with `ngAfterViewInIt` and assigned data to it, fixed the `string` declaration on the interface variable but still the table is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the modules directly in `app.module.ts`

Comment: already tried this , still nothing

Comment: still stuck, help please